# Find or restore wiki pages. (Computer will not boot anymore and need the wiki pages)

Tags: mysql, restore, wiki

A few years ago, where I work, I created a wiki for me and my co-workers.  We work on a lot of old programs and to help with cross training, we put a lot of our notes in the wiki.

Sadly, the wiki was hosted on my machine and my machine has died.  I can pull the drive out and hook it up to an enclosure and still see the files, etc.  I want to know...is there a way to get the files/pages from that wiki somehow.  I think they are stored in a mysql database somewhere.  Yeah it sucks and I had a lot of stuff on that drive but the most important thing for me now is to get those notes (wiki pages).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the wiki software used?

Comment: Not really programming related unless you want to know how to programmaticly retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Find where the database is. If it's on a Windows XP mine defaulted to area below:

```
datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
```

In that directory there will be something like "mywiki".   In the `mywiki` directory there will hopefully be lots of files ending in ".frm". and a db.opt file.

Copy the "mywiki" directory from the bad disk into the same place on your newly installed mysql. Start mysql and at this point if you are lucky you should be able to see the database in mysql with `show databases`, use the tables etc.  Make sure and use a copy, chances are you will get lucky and nothing will be corrupted when mysql mounts this.

You are going to have to find out what the old wiki software was and then either copy/reinstall it to your system as before and point it at your database.

Hopefully that's it.

Then start doing `mysqldump` on a schedule and storing it somewhere safe.